# how to select rows in a pandas dataframe from a column with a categoricalDtype using a logical operator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I have a column in a pandas dataframe that is a categorical data type, how can I select the rows using a logical operator ?

for example if I have :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=150), columns=['whatever'])
df_bins=np.linspace(df.min(),df.max(),101)
df['bin']=pd.cut(df.iloc[:,0],df_bins)
```

df['bin'] is an ordered categorical Dtype. How to select the rows whose intervals are e.g. bigger than a certain value. If I do

```
df['bin']>50
```

I get an error saying that I cannot compare categorical with a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `IntervalIndex` and `left`

```
pd.IntervalIndex(df['bin']).left>50
Out[28]: 
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
       False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,
       False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False])
```